# Add div (or something else) atop png image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, png

So, I have done some searching for this, however, I'm not even quite sure what I'm looking for. Forgive me if this question has already been addressed.

I want to take an image, eg:
http://torreybraman.com/dev/circlechart.jpg

and make a png where the cells are empty.
Then, I want to add text to those cells via some sort of div or something equivalent.

Also, the data within these "cells" will be changing often but the overall layout will always be the same.

I know how to fill divs from a datasource, but I have no edea how I would fill and ROTATE the data within the cells to go around the circle.

Is there a way kind of like photoshop adding text boxes (with some WYSIWYG editor)?

I just don't know where to start. I need the easiest way to do this without extensive html/css/javascript knowledge.

Thanks!

Comment: Would you consider "extensive" the use of CSS `transform` property? It looks like it's all you need.

Comment: I don't know if there is a way through a WSYIWYG editor, but what you would need is to set this .png as a `background-image` of a `div` in your css file, then, add as many div elements as you need, one per each cell, and give them a `position: absolute` with the correct `left` and `top` properties, plus to rotate the text you would need  the `transform` CSS rule.

Comment: Awesome. So would each cell and its respective dive need its own css styling? I will definitely look into that. (not closing the question till I try it. If anyone else also has input let me know).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a less-elegant example - brute force - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/E7zap/).

It moves on hover.

CSS

```
.holder {
    width: 450px;
    height: 442px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-image: url(http://torreybraman.com/dev/circlechart.jpg);
    background-size: 550 550;
    background-repeat: none;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 5s;
}
.holder:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
#seca5 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 5px;
    transform: rotate(-70deg);
}
#secc5 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 14px;
    left: 190px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
#sece5 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 370px;
    transform: rotate(70deg);
}
#sech5 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 410px;
    left: 200px;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Comment: This is close to what I have gotten to via trial and error, but a bit more accurate. This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is something that dynamically does the trick. Ask away if you have any question about it.

[JSBin demo](http://jsbin.com/nibunuyi/1/edit).

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="/dev/circlehart.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 450px;
}
.word {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var words = ["Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet,", "consectetuer",
        "adipiscing", "elit,", "sed", "diam", "nonummy", "nibh", "euismod",
        "tincidunt", "ut", "laoreet", "dolore", "magna", "aliquam", "erat",
        "volutpat.", "Ut", "wisi", "enim", "ad", "minim", "veniam,", "quis",
        "nostrud", "exerci", "tation", "ullamcorper", "suscipit", "lobortis",
        "nisl", "ut", "aliquip", "ex", "ea", "commodo", "consequat."],
    wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper"),
    xformProp = ["transform", "webkitTransform", "msTransform", "mozTransform"]
        .filter(function(p) {return p in this;}, wrapper.style)[0],
    i = 0, box;

for (; i < words.length; i++) {
    box = document.createElement("div");
    box.className = "word";
    box.appendChild(document.createTextNode(words[i]));
    wrapper.appendChild(box);
    box.style[xformProp] = "translate(-" + (box.offsetWidth/2) + "px, -"
            + (box.offsetHeight/2) + "px) rotate(" + (i % 10) * 36 + "deg)"
            + " translateY(" + (22 - (5 - Math.floor(i / 10)) * 45) + "px)";
}
```

Comment: A bit beyond my skill set but excellent none the less. I will be looking into this farther so I don't have to do it all individually next time.